# Convergence of series knowing convergence of another series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'd appreciate any hint for this problem. I have some variables $x_i$ that satisfy $\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{x_i}=1$ for any $N$. What can I say about the series $\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{N^2}{x_i^2i^2}$? In particular, does this series have a finite value when $N\to\infty$?

I tried to reason as follows, but it seems to me my procedure has some flaws. Since $\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{x_i}=1$ it must be $x_i\sim N$ so that summing $N$ of these variables gives one. Then we can write $x_i=N c_i$ and consequently $\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{N^2}{x_i^2i^2}=\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{c_i^2i^2}$. Moreover $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{c_i}=1$, as a consequence $\frac{1}{x_i}=o(1)$. This implies that $\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{c_i^2i^2}<\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{i^2}<\infty$.

The problem of this procedure is that even if the typical $x_i$ must satisfy $x_i\sim N$, there can be some $x_i$ that do not scale with $N$ and this would make the second series diverge. Any idea about how to approach this problem?

Comment: You could as well just take $x_i$ instead of $\frac{1}{x_i}$. I mean, $\sum_{i=1}^N x_i=1$ and $N^2\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{x_i^2}{i^2}$. Btw, are $x_i$ all positive?

Comment: What's to approach? Like you said yourself in the last paragraph, the new series can diverge all right.

Comment: The $x_i$ are all positives. But yes the new series can diverge or converge depending on the $x_i$, not much to say unfortunately. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I will rewrite the question to be a little bit more formal. For every $N$ let $X_N=\{x\in(0,+\infty)^N|\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{x_i}=1\}$ and let $F_N:X_N\rightarrow(0,+\infty):x\mapsto\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{N^2}{x_i^2 i^2}$. You are asking what could the limit $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}F_N(y_k)$ be for $y_k\in X_k$ for every $k$ (i.e. $y\in\prod_{i=1}^\infty X_i$). I will prove that this sequence could be anything in that limit. In other words $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\inf\{F_N(x)|x\in X_N\}=0$ and $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sup\{F_N(x)|x\in X_N\}=\infty$. The second one is a little easier so let's do that one first. Take arbitrary $M>1$. Set $x_1=M$ and $x_k=\frac{(N-1)M}{M-1},\forall k>1$. The condition is satisfied and $F_N(x)>\frac{N^2}{x_1^2}=\frac{N^2}{M^2}$. Since $M>1$ was arbitrary we can take $M=2$ and get $F_N(x)=\frac{N^2}{4}$. We must have $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sup\{F_N(x)|x\in X_N\}\ge\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{N^2}{4}=\infty$. That finishes the second limit. For the first limit, it can be shown (for ex. by Legendre multipliers method) that $x_i=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N i^2}{i^2}$ in fact reaches the minimum. In that case we get $F_N(x)=N^2\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{i^2}{\big(\sum_{i=1}^N i^2\big)^2}=\frac{N^2}{\sum_{i=1}^N i^2}\approx\frac{3}{N}$. And we get $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\inf\{F_N(x)|x\in X_N\}\le\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{3}{N}=0$. Then we have that the domain of $F_N$ is connected and $F_N$ is continuous because it is polynomial, so the image of $F_N$ must be connected. This means the whole interval from $\frac{3}{N}$ to $\frac{N^2}{4}$ must be hit for some vector. This means that the limit you have been looking for can be anything.